# Import old android studio configuration settings into new android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android studio in Ubuntu.Now I am using **Android Studio V1.4**.
I already downloaded **Android studio 2.0 Preview 3b** bundle.My question is that I have many projects in current(Android Studio V1.4) studio,And I want my previous(Android Studio V1.4) studio configuration settings with all my projects in  my new Android studio.How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can export your settings by selecting file -> Export Settings
Import vice versa.

[Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BA6b.png)
[Export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsEO9.png)